# how to use a variable in two different forms c# windows forms

Tags: forms, variables

i have 5 forms in my application from which i want to use variables from the one form and call it on another. I have a car wash form and a trade - in form.  If i wanted to call carwash total and add it with the trade in total for the end of day sales how would i do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code to attempt to do this yet? Errors at all?

Comment: im new to programming so i tried to google it but to no evale. so what i did was when i go to the next form i would leave the active one open and just manually enter the value in the next form.

Comment: and no errors at all. i also tried to type in the form name next to the class eg public class CarWash : Trade_in

that gave me an error so i just left it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Form getters and setters to access and modify such variables.

```
public class CarWash: Form
{
   ...
   public type carWashVariable { get; set; }
   ...           
}

From Trade form:    
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(CarWash.carWashVariable);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply like i said im new to all this and yet so excited to learn.....i started a new project just to test what you said above. on the trade form i can only pick up carwash form but not the variable on the carwash form the code i have there is error free. im sure im simple mistake, i wana leave it but i also wanna know how to for future reference.....how do i load up my code that way it would be easier to spot my mistake. thank you